# Can bioluminescence be used for cancer or tumor detection?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, health, cancer

What diagnostic applications, if any, are there in using bioluminescence to detect cancer or tumors (in vivo)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your intenstions? E.g. are you talking *in vivo* labeling (patients) or *in vitro* (cell cultures).

Comment: A list of all possible applications would make a very long textbook. If you could narrow that down to just diagnostic applications for example, that would help greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in human but you can use this technique with genetically modified model organisms as described [here](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/aalas/cm/2004/00000054/00000006/art00005?token=004a10c8405847447b49762f7b7342425e2079475833757e6f4f2858592f3f3b579225a506).

The procedure is quite simple, you express the luciferase enzyme under the control of a specific promoter (specific for your cell type, like cancer) and provide luciferin via intravascular or intraperitoneal injection. The targeted cell type (for example cancer) will light up.

If you want to use that as a **diagnostic tool in human you can't** as the organism must express an enzyme catalyzing a bioluminescent reaction. Actually with the advance of genome engineering tools you might be able to do that even in humans (e.g. using [CRISP/Cas9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR)).

What is the advantage of bioluminescence over fluorescence? I might be wrong but I don't think there are any. I would rather express a fluorophore rather than an enzyme that requires a substrat.

Comment: What would a cancer specific promoter be? You could target a particular cell type, but how would you distinguish between tumorous and healthy? They have the same promoters. You could, perhaps, use promoters that are only active in proliferating cells but that limits the usefulness of the approach. More importantly, how would you detect the bioluminescence in, say, the liver?

Comment: @terdon several exist. See this [list](http://www.invivogen.com/tumor-specific-promoter) for example. I agree you can't detect bioluminescence of internal organs but strictly speaking you can use bioluminescence to detect (some type of) cancer cells which was the question (can it be used?). I also don't think bioluminescence is a great detection tool but this would be my opinion and not actual facts.

Comment: Huh, I stand corrected, thanks. I didn't know there were tumor-specific promoters.

Comment: @terdon, well you are not completely wrong :) Some promoters are more/less express (which give them the "specific" tag) in tumors than normal cells but there are, as far as I know, no promoters totally OFF in normal cell and totally ON in tumor cell or vice-versa. Still that should be sufficient to apply that technique.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes more sense. I was having trouble imagining how a promoter could be completely specific to tumor cells.

Comment: @terdon. biology has a special usage of the term "specific"...

Comment: I don't think CRISPR would be appropriate to insert an entire luciferase gene. The luciferase gene is just too large, and if you could get the luciferase template DNA into the cell, why not just deliver the whole working plasmid instead of relying on CRISPR to correctly insert it?

Comment: As far as using mice goes, you can get expression of luciferase/GFP through something like lentiviral transfection to a subconfluent tumor cell culture. Non-invasive imaging equipment like IVIS 200 can then be used to view luminescence *in vivo*. We're generally detecting grafted tumor cells, however, so i don't believe the process exists to simply detect new tumors, especially in humans.

Comment: @Kendall Agree. I am also quite certain it does not exist in human. My answer is tailored to the question which is "using bioluminescence to detect cancer or tumors (in vivo)?". Does not speak about any organisms or about native, induced or graphed tumors so I just went as general as the question is.

Comment: @user137 I just mentioned that as an eventuality to apply that to humans one day. For model organisms I agree any ways of delivering the construct should do. This goes way beyond the question but CRIPSR/Cas9 actually might be required as if you want to do genome engineering in humans you need to insert the gene in a very specific location in the genome as you probably cannot directly target only tumors cells but likely just some closely-related cell types. In a more general view, to be one day applied, genome engineering will have to be very specific in the genome modifications provoked.

Comment: @Kendall [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23229091) shows that existing tumors in mice can be transfected with mRNA. It's not high level expression yet, but you could use something like this to make cancer cells express luciferase, or a suicide gene.

Answer (score 0):

*In vivo*, none.

Bioluminescence is cool, but it's not a powerful light source. Even if you could tag a cancer cell (all of them), unless it were on your skin or in your eye, you wouldn't be able to see it, even with some kind of scope.

Comment: Wrong you actually can.

Comment: @cagliari2005 Can you then elaborate your comment?

Comment: @chris writing an answer right now

Answer (score 0):

Bioluminescence could not be used but it is possible to 'tag' with fluorescence to better view pathways within the body. Tagging is often used in research, a simple google search should produce a plethora of results.